# Улица: Пушкина или Пушкинская?

Tags: словоформы

Часто в просторечии говоря о какой-то улице, названной в честь известного человека, мы употребляем вариант не, например, ул. Пушкина, а Пушкинская, не ул. Лермонтова, а Лермонтовская и т.д.
Понятно, что это, так сказать, обиходная форма. Но может ли она быть официальной? Грамотно ли это вообще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Текст бы написан до появления других ответов, по техническим причинам не удалось отправить сразу. Если опоздал - извините.*

**Fuchoin Kazuki**, это два равновозможных варианта названия - но их нельзя смешивать.
Если улица названа *Пушкинской*, то она никак не *"ул. Пушкина"*. И наоборот. Если это *"улица Пушкина"*, то не стоит называть её *Пушкинской*. Это приведет к путанице. 
В Москве какое-то время сосуществовали несколько *Пушкинских* и *"ул. Пушкина"* - за счет присоединения новых территорий. И без того путаницы хватало.

В Петербурге, Харькове, Киеве - ул. Пушкинская. 
В Екатеринбурге, Самаре, Волгограде - Пушкина.
(Города мне не чужие, остальные опускаю)

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0

Есть некоторая очень слабая тенденция называть улицы в честь Имерекова - "ул. Имярекова" и "ул. Имярековская" в зависимости от непосредственного пребывания Имерекова на зтой улице. Но очень слабая, на два правила - три исключения.

Answer (score 2):

> > Часто в просторечии говоря о какой-то улице, названной в честь известного человека, мы употребляем вариант не, например, ул. Пушкина, а Пушкинская

Это ВЫ такой вариант употребляете? Странно... Ни разу не слышал.

> > Понятно, что это, так сказать, обиходная форма.

Да нисколько. Более того, раньше именно так улицы и назывались.

Comment: Вообще-то, наша улица Пушкина до революции ОФИЦИАЛЬНО называлась Пушкинская. Так что, Ваша ирония не к месту.

Comment: Так  он  и  говорит: раньше  именно  так  улицы  и  назывались.

Answer (score 1):

> Может ли она [такая форма] быть официальной?

Да, в Вологде есть Пушкинская улица. Такой вариант вполне себе приемлем и нераспространенность такой формы связано лишь с модой и возможной двусмысленностью, например, если бы площадь им. Бабушкина в той же Вологде имела бы наименование Бабушкинская (так ее часто называют в народе), можно было бы подумать, что свое имя она получила не от революционера Бабушкина, а в честь какой-то старой женщины.

Comment: В Москве, однако, куча всего "бабушкинского", ни к какми бабашкам отношения не имеющего. От школ - до района (бывшего). Ничего, не путают. Главное - привычка.

Answer (score 0):

У нас в Петербурге всегда говорят конкретно, в соответствии с официальным наименованием, поскольку встречается и то, и другое, напр. официально есть Пушкинская улица, улица Ленина и Ленинский проспект. Иногда названия улиц складываются по недоразумению или из просторечий. Например, ул. Большая Зеленина произошла от Большой Зелейной (там порох делали), а "улица Карташихина" (гражданина с такой фамилией не было) от канцеляризации "Карташихиной улицы" (в честь владевшей домами Карташихи, по фамилии Карташевой; одно из бывших названий - Карташевская), и вышло так именно от стремления всё сделать единообразно и "грамотно".

Comment: Мало кто знает, с изобретением бездымного пороха ее и переименовали, а все потому, что порох этот зеленый.  Так что и ничего удивительного в этом нет.

Answer (score 0):

Надо употреблять название улицы именно так, как она официально называется, чтобы не путаться. Ведь иногда возможны оба варианта официальных названий.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, это совершенно разные улицы, и нельзя заменять одно другим.

Answer (score 0):

Принцип называть объекты городской топонимии именами известных или связываемых с местом людей специалисты по названиям именуют антропонимическим(в отличие от географического, церковного, ремесленного, по названию гражданских, военных или других  объектов и др. принципов).

Было время(ХVIII-XIXвв) - иначе, чем Пушкинская, Лефортовская, Ришельевская, Екатерининская, Дерибасовская, Скобелевская, Гоголевская и т.п. улицы, площади и разные проезды и спуски не имели права называться. В советское время появились не только Пролетарские или Красногвардейские переулки, но и улицы имени Ленина, Калинина(или Калининские - по старой традиции), или просто без слова "имени" - улицы Толстого, Пушкина, Лермонтова, Чапаева и проч.

Только за несколько десятков лет главный симферопольский "брод(вей)" дважды менял официальное название сначала (в 20-е годы) с Пушкинской улицы на улицу Пушкина и вновь на Пушкинскую(уже в новые времена).

Называть в обиходе эти улицы можно как угодно, как привычнее, но всегда помните, что у привычной и любимой многими Метростроевской есть возвращенное официальное название "Остоженка". И теперь это не простецкий пролетарский райончик(как же - метростроители), а заповедник миллионеров и миллионерш.